# Django Project: Trying to understand why my Django project is showing the error Understanding TypeError Invalid path type list:

Tags: python, django

I am trying to understand why my Django project is saying that it cannot understand my paths. According the instructions of the book django for beginners I need to run the python manage.py runserver command to load the website but it stops me.

It shows the following when I get the error:

Error Message

```
(.venv) andrewstribling@Andrews-MBP pages % python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/andrewstribling/Desktop/code/pages/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/andrewstribling/Desktop/code/pages/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/andrewstribling/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/andrewstribling/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 436, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/andrewstribling/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 412, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/andrewstribling/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 74, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/andrewstribling/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 458, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/andrewstribling/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 111, in handle
    self.run(**options)
  File "/Users/andrewstribling/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 118, in run
    autoreload.run_with_reloader(self.inner_run, **options)
  File "/Users/andrewstribling/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 671, in run_with_reloader
    start_django(reloader, main_func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/andrewstribling/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 660, in start_django
    reloader.run(django_main_thread)
  File "/Users/andrewstribling/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 343, in run
    autoreload_started.send(sender=self)
  File "/Users/andrewstribling/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 176, in send
    return [
  File "/Users/andrewstribling/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 177, in <listcomp>
    (receiver, receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named))
  File "/Users/andrewstribling/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/template/autoreload.py", line 43, in watch_for_template_changes
    for directory in get_template_directories():
  File "/Users/andrewstribling/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/template/autoreload.py", line 20, in get_template_directories
    items.update(cwd / to_path(dir) for dir in backend.engine.dirs if dir)
  File "/Users/andrewstribling/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/template/autoreload.py", line 20, in <genexpr>
    items.update(cwd / to_path(dir) for dir in backend.engine.dirs if dir)
  File "/Users/andrewstribling/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/utils/_os.py", line 61, in to_path
    raise TypeError("Invalid path type: %s" % type(value).__name__)
TypeError: Invalid path type: list
```

as for how my code:

## django_project urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include 

urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("", include("pages.urls")), 
]
```

pages urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import HomePageView

urlpatterns = [
    path("", HomePageView().as_view(), name="home"),
]
```

settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for django_project project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.2.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = "django-insecure-gh%z)%nhp0m3t%mo&2%k!7*^q^#rkt%7_exly%=%6(0_ae=ss0"

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "pages",
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
]

ROOT_URLCONF = "django_project.urls"

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [[BASE_DIR / "templates"]],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = "django_project.wsgi.application"


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.sqlite3",
        "NAME": BASE_DIR / "db.sqlite3",
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator",
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = "en-us"

TIME_ZONE = "UTC"

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = "static/"

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = "django.db.models.BigAutoField"
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render 

from django.views.generic import TemplateView

# Create your views here.

class HomePageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "home.html"
```

What steps have I tried and what am I expecting?

I have tried moving my folders around, I have tried restarting and running the same commands again. I have tried searching on stackoverflow for articles related to the subject. I have tried checking the python documentation.

I have tried relooking at the instructions but I swear I have followed them to the letter.

Any ideas?

Comment: share the `TEMPLATES` setting.

Comment: You've included the views.py file twice.

Comment: Show us the `pages/urls.py` file.  The one here is wrong.

Comment: In your settings `TEMPLATES['DIRS']` should be a list of paths, you are passing a list of lists. Change `"DIRS": [[BASE_DIR / "templates"]],` to be `"DIRS": [BASE_DIR / "templates"],`

Comment: @IainShelvington if you answer I will award you the checkmark. Willem you were right as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove parentheses () after HomePageView in urls.py file. File should be look like this:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import HomePageView

urlpatterns = [
    path("", HomePageView.as_view(), name="home"),
]
```